# An equivalent of text for the imageView

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I would like to know what is the equivalent of this :

```
textView!!.text = getResources().getString(R.string.text)
```

But in my case I have an ImageView and I want to change it in the Kotlin code I tried :

```
image!!.getResources().getString(R.drawable.image)
```

But it does not work...Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can set like this,

```
image!!.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.image)
```

Comment: I don't understand why but it has no effects ! :/

Comment: This is how we should set the drawable to the imageView in Kotlin, Please check your drawable and also check your layout.

Comment: This doesn't set the image to the view though, it just loads it and then does nothing with it

Answer (score 2):

You can set an image with setImageDrawable() or setImageResource()

```
image?.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)
```

Or the equivalent, but longer version:

```
image?.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image))
```

---

(Also note the question mark instead of double exclamation marks. Now, if image is null, it just skips this line instead of throwing an exception)